# Failed to fetch updates Again!

Tags: updates

I installed elementary Os again a fresh install but after installation when i headed to app centre for updates it says failed to fetch updates. This happens to me everytime when i install elementary but everytime the cause is different now its an icon is not yet available. Also this is my second fresh install of the day the 1st time i did i updates using terminal but this same error popped up so i started started again and so hear i am. This is the 13th time thsi has happened to me this year.Is is something to do with me ,is it my fault for not doing something right?[image]

[image]

Comment: Updates come from repositories hosted on servers. Those servers might be unavailable at times, or might contain invalid information. Try the approved solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505775/debian-apt-packages-hash-sum-mismatch and let us know if it fixed your issue.

Comment: no i have tried it it didn't work that was the whole reason why i posted this question

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error/), hash sum mismatch errors are usually more typical for clients behind proxy caches. To solve the issue, remove all the content of `/var/lib/apt/lists directory`:

Type in the terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then type:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

It should solve the issue. Ask your Internet Service Provider do they use some proxy. If yes. Then ask can they disable proxy for you.

Comment: I have found two solution for proxy. One is this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/583797/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-terminal This is the second: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/ Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu so both solutions will work.